# SQL query time out for Report with 14 Columns (14 days)

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

```
if (myMandays == 1)
                Filter1 = " count(empno)";
            else
                Filter1 = " sum(mdays)";

            switch (myKcodeInt)
            {
                case 1:
                    Filter2 = "";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Filter2 = " and a.khead = @myKcodeStr";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Filter2 = " and a.kcode = @myKcodeStr";
                    break;

                default:
                    Filter2 = " and a.ktype = @myKcodeStr";
                    break;
            }
            switch (myShiftno)
            {
                case 1:
                    Filter3 = " and shiftno IN (1,2,5)";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Filter3 = " and shiftno = 1";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Filter3 = " and shiftno = 2";
                    break;

                default:
                    Filter3 = " and shiftno = 5";
                    break;
            }
            //commandText = "Select * from Wageentry where " +  Filter1 + " and empno in (Select empno from Empmain)";
            commandText = @"Select a.kdesc,a.kcode,b.khead,b.khdesc,a.emandays,a.eamt,a.wtype,a.wtype2,
            (Select " + Filter1 + @"from WageEntry where kdate = (@date1) and kcode = a.kcode" + Filter3 + @") as day1,
            (Select " + Filter1 + @"from WageEntry where kdate = (@date2) and kcode = a.kcode" + Filter3 + @") as day2,
            (Select " + Filter1 + @"from WageEntry where kdate = (@date3) and kcode = a.kcode" + Filter3 + @") as day3,
            (Select " + Filter1 + @"from WageEntry where kdate = (@date4) and kcode = a.kcode" + Filter3 + @") as day4,
            (Select " + Filter1 + @"from WageEntry where kdate = (@date5) and kcode = a.kcode" + Filter3 + @") as day5,
            (Select " + Filter1 + @"from WageEntry where kdate = (@date6) and kcode = a.kcode" + Filter3 + @") as day6,
            (Select " + Filter1 + @"from WageEntry where kdate = (@date7) and kcode = a.kcode" + Filter3 + @") as day7,
            (Select " + Filter1 + @"from WageEntry where kdate = (@date8) and kcode = a.kcode" + Filter3 + @") as day8,
            (Select " + Filter1 + @"from WageEntry where kdate = (@date9) and kcode = a.kcode" + Filter3 + @") as day9,
            (Select " + Filter1 + @"from WageEntry where kdate = (@date10) and kcode = a.kcode" + Filter3 + @") as day10,
            (Select " + Filter1 + @"from WageEntry where kdate = (@date11) and kcode = a.kcode" + Filter3 + @") as day11,
            (Select " + Filter1 + @"from WageEntry where kdate = (@date12) and kcode = a.kcode" + Filter3 + @") as day12,
            (Select " + Filter1 + @"from WageEntry where kdate = (@date13) and kcode = a.kcode" + Filter3 + @") as day13,
            (Select " + Filter1 + @"from WageEntry where kdate = (@date14) and kcode = a.kcode" + Filter3 + @") as day14,
            (Select " + Filter1 + @"from WageEntry where kdate between (@date1) and (@date14) and kcode = a.kcode" + Filter3 + @") as mandays,
            (Select sum(wageamt+addamt+overtime) from WageEntry where kdate between (@date1) and (@date14) and kcode = a.kcode " + Filter3 + @") as totalamt,
            (Select sum(wageamt) from WageEntry where kdate between (@date1) and (@date14) and kcode = a.kcode" + Filter3 + @") as wageamt,
            (Select sum(addamt) from WageEntry where kdate between (@date1) and (@date14) and kcode = a.kcode" + Filter3 + @") as addamt,
            (Select sum(overtime) from WageEntry where kdate between (@date1) and (@date14) and kcode = a.kcode" + Filter3 + @") as overtime, 
            (@date1) as sdate,(@date14) as edate
            from kamjaricode a,kamjarihead b
            where a.khead = b.khead" + Filter2 + " order by khead,kcode";
```

This is for a report. Start date & filters are set from UI. It's a 14 day report of mandays deployed. With local server and data for one year it was working but once I moved the data to Azure and added 10 years data the report query started Timeout.

```
Work code A1 day1 day2 day3 ..... day14
Work code A2 day1 day2 day3 ..... day14
Work code A3 day1 day2 day3 ..... day14
Work code A4 day1 day2 day3 ..... day14
Work code A5 day1 day2 day3 ..... day14
Group A Sub-Total
.
.
.
Grand Total for each day for each column.
```

This is how the report will look like.

OPTION2:

Generate the datatable dt for 14 days with zero values.
Then generate datatable for each day & replace column in dt.

Final Output

[image]

Comment: It sounds like there could be performance issues with your query. Often Azure will identify these for you, have a loot at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/database-advisor-implement-performance-recommendations) article. Another option would be to take a look at the exeuction plan of your query for any recomendations. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/display-an-actual-execution-plan?view=sql-server-ver15) article

Comment: Why so many subqueries on `WageEntry` do it all in one join?

Comment: @Charlieface Each subquery returns data for a particular date. The query is for 14 days. I have no idea how to do it in one join.

Comment: join without `kdate = (@date1)` then you need to pivot the join result on dates

Comment: @Charlieface Thanks I think its done that way. Let me read a few examples.